# sed match multiple lines containing special characters and replace part of the matched pattern

Tags: bash, shell, sed

Consider the following set of lines as a text file:

```
START This is a 
sample paragraph that has special characters like new lines

spaces, tabs, quotes "abc", equals =, angular brackets <abc>, front slash / and might contain the starting string that should be ignored
START and 

END

START

dfgfah

END
```

Using sed, I want to replace text between only the first occurrence of `START` and the first occurrence of `END`.

The result that I am expecting is like:

```
START new_text END

START

dfgfah

END
```

**What I tried is like:**

```sh
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/START.*END/START New text END/' sample.txt>sample_2.txt
```

But the result was:

```
START New text End
```

How do I replace until the first occurrence of `END`?

Comment: This would be trivial with Perl: `perl -0777 -pe 's/START.*?END/START New text END/s'`

Comment: Is perl supported on all flavors of linux?
It has to be supported on SuSe, IBM NIX,and few other flavors

Comment: Perl runs on pretty much all operating systems (including Linux and more esoteric stuff like HP/UX, VMS, etc). I don't know whether it is part of the standard OS install, however.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed:

```
sed '0,/START/{:a;/END/!{N;ba};s/.*/START new_text END/;}' file
```

- `0,/START/`: from first occurrence of `START`
- `:a;/END/!{N;ba}`: append new lines to the pattern space until `END` is found
- when above loops ends, replace merged lines with `START new_text END`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:` do define labels and `b` to branch to the label in `sed` scripts.

The option `-n` tells `sed` to print no lines automatically. Instead you can print the lines with the `p` command.

In the following example the `:head` loop loops over the part up to the first `START` and the `:tail` loop loops over the text after the first `END`. The `:start` loop loops over the part between the first `START` and `END`.

The `:head` and `:tail` loops print (`p`) every line (`n`) and quit, when they reach the end of the file (`$q`). The `:start` loop does not print and just ignores the content. When the `END` is found, the new text gets inserted (`s`) and printed (`p`).

```
cat <<EOF |
START This is a 
sample paragraph that has special characters like new lines

spaces, tabs, quotes "abc", equals =, angular brackets <abc>, front slash / and might contain the starting string that should be ignored
START and 

END

START

dfgfah

END
EOF
sed -n '
:head
/^START/{
  :start
  n
  $q
  /^END/{
    s/^/START New text /
    p
    n
    :tail
    p
    $q
    n
    b tail
  }
  b start
}
p
$q
n
b head
'
```

The above technique is taken from the first example of [The Geek Stuff's `sed` tutorial](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/12/unix-sed-tutorial-6-examples-for-sed-branching-operation/).